# How to know when every conclusion has been derived from a set of statements?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Let us say that we have 3 statements:

```
1. A>B
2. B>C
3.A
```

From here, a total of 3 conclusions can be reached:
    ____________________________________________________________________

```
4. B
5. C
6. A>C
```

It is clear that here, all the possible conclusions that could be derived, has been derived, and is also clear as to what the proof is for each derivation to the trained logician.

Howewer, given a more complex premise, say:

```
1. A+B
2. A=(C&D)
3. B>(D&G)
4. ~D+G
5. ~G
```

Whilst it may (or may not) be clear as to how one may go about deriving a single statement, it's not at all clear as to how one would go about deriving an exhaustive list of all statements.

I believe this is important because there may be one derivation that does not logically contradict another, but it does so via the context under which those derivations are being made (i.e the significance it bears on the real world). Or maybe they do not contradict each other, but they reinforce each other in such a way that can only be known by the agent constructing such a proof.

Now, of course with respects to logic itself, the context of the situation does not matter. However, the question as to "How can we know when all conclusions have been derived" is a question concerning pure logic, and because an answer to such a question does have real-world implications, I think it's a question worth asking.

Note: I do not include as part of the set of all derivations those that are logically true or false, for e.g A+B, A+(B&D), A&F, etc.

Comment: Instead of writing `>`, `+`, `&` and `~`, consider using mathjax, where `$A \implies B$`, `$A\lor B$`, `$A \land B$` and `$\neg A$` produce text like this: $A \implies B$, $A\lor B$, $A \land B$ and $\neg A$

Comment: Oh hey, what's mathjax if you don't mind me asking? I imagine it doesn't acutally turn out like "$A \implies B$"?

Comment: Ahhh, right, I see (literally) haha

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Ah yes, I read that before posting, it seems he was only referring to the specific set of premises he outlined, rather than a method that could be applied to any set of statements.

Comment: I don't agree when you say that from the first three statements a total of three conclusions ($B$, $C$, $A \to C$) can be derived. You can also derive $B \lor C$, $B \land C$, $B \land B$, $B \lor B$, $B \land B \land B \land B \land C, \dots$ Note that $B \lor C$ is not equivalent to $B$ (or $C$ or $A \to C$).

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco You are right, though I added a note at the end that I was not including vacuous conclusions as part of the set of derivations I was looking to derive. In other worlds am looking only for the set of all conclusions that are contingently true (from any given premise)

Comment: I wouldn't call them "vacuous", but instead use logical equivalence to describe that formulas have been derived already. Vacuous means "empty", while to me those formulas definitely appear to have content (although logically $B\land B$ has the same content as $B$)

Comment: Why should $∧∧∧∧$ be considered as a vacuous conclusion, while $A \to C$ not?

Comment: Well, first of all, ∧∧∧∧ collapses into ∧. Second of all, with respects to either derivation, they're only vacuous if 1. They were not one of the original premises (otherwise we have not learned anything), and 2. They are not logically true. If they're logically true, then they're true regardless of the state of the world. 

Wheather either of the premises, you just put forth is vacuous or not is dependent upon the argument itself.

Comment: @JimJam The problem is not with your intention, it is with the use of the word "vacuous".

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco: "*You can also derive* ..." --- I was thinking the same thing when I read the question, but you got to it first!

Comment: @Vsotvep I didn't mean vacuous in the usual term, as if to say it's a stupid conclusion (of course there is no such thing in logic), but in the technical sense, as in not contingent. But maybe a better alternative should be used anyway.

Comment: @JimJam - So, according to your definition, also $B$, $C$, and $A \to C$ are vacuous conclusions (they are different from the premises and they are not tautologies).

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, "They are different from the premises and are not tautologies", these were the two conditions I defined as being *not* vacuous. Anyway, I changed the terminology in my final note from "Vacuous" to "Contingent".

Comment: @JimJam - This is what you wrote: "they're only vacuous if 1. They were not one of the original premises (otherwise we have not learned anything), and 2. They are not logically true". More in general, please, give a precise definition of what vacuous means.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, Ah right you are. In that case, I shall make the necessary corrections to my original comment. Nevermind, I cannot edit, in which case please take the two conditions I put forth to mean "Not vacuous" instead of "vacous"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An *exhaustive* list of all formulas that can be derived is not finite, since there are infinitely many logical formulas that you could derive even without any assumptions. For example, you could always derive the tautologies $A\to A;$  $A\to(A\to A);$ $A\to(A\to(A\to A))$, etc.

So perhaps it is better to work with equivalence classes of formulas, since if $A$ and $B$ are equivalent to each other, then we can always use the proof of this equivalence to transform a proof of $A$ into a proof of $B$.

To be precise, instead of working with *formulas* $\phi$, we work with *sets of formulas* $[\phi]$, being the set of all formulas that are provably equivalent to $\phi$. We call such a set $[\phi]$ an equivalence class.

A formula $\psi$ is part of the equivalence class of $\phi$ if $\psi\leftrightarrow \phi$ is provable. For example, $B$ and $B\land B$ and $(A\lor\lnot A)\land B$ are all provably equivalent to each other, so they are all part of the same equivalence class.

This is probably what you meant with "vacuous".

---

Throughout the following I assume we're working with a finite set of premises, although it could be generalised to work with infinitely many premises.

### Idea 1

Remember that a proof is nothing more than a finite list of formulas, such that each formula is either an axiom, a premise, or follows from an earlier formula in the list by the use of a *derivation rule*.

The precise specifics of what these axioms and derivation rules are, depends on the proof system you use, but the following idea works similarly for any proof system with a finite number of axioms and derivation rules. For example, you could use a [Hilbert system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) for propositional logic. On that link there is an example of one with four axioms and a single derivation rule (modus ponens).

We can then define the *length* of a proof as the length of the list of formulas that make up the proof.

Generating the set of derivable formulas from a given set of premises is now quite "easy":

1. Go through all proofs of length $1$ with your starting premises, and add each conclusion to your list of derivable formulas. (At this stage the list will contain only axioms and premises, since those are the only proofs of $1$ length)
2. Go through all proofs of length $2$, and add all conclusions to your list. (These will be all the formulas that are directly derivable from the axioms or premises using a derivation rule).
3. Go through all proofs of length $3$, and add all conclusions to your list.
4. You get the point ....

Since there are only finitely many derivation rules and axioms in a reasonable proof system for propositional logic, there are only a finite number of proofs of a given length $n$, so this process is possible, although it is an infinite process.

If you skip writing down formulas in your list that are logically equivalent to an earlier formula, you will get a list of formulas that are all *unique* with regard to logical equivalence. If you start with finitely many premises, there will be finitely many formulas in your list.

One problem with this approach is that we don't know if we have found all equivalence classes that are derivable: we don't know if we can stop at a given moment, or if we will still find new formulas if we keep going.

### Idea 2

Another way would be to use semantics (so for propositional logic, this means *[truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)*) and the fact that propositional logic is complete: if we can prove an implication using truth tables, then we can find a derivation for it in our proof system (e.g. the Hilbert system I mentioned before).

There are at most $2^{2^m}$ equivalence classes of formulas using $m$ propositional variables. You can prove this by looking at truth tables: the equivalence class to which a formula belongs is decided by which rows of the truth table make it valid. If two formulas are valid on exactly the same rows, then those two formulas are equivalent to each other.

There are $2^m$ rows, hence $2^{2^m}$ possible combinations of these rows, each giving an equivalence class.

As an example, take the propositional variables $p_1,\dots,p_m$, and define for each subset $A\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ the formula

$$\varphi_{A}=\left(\bigwedge_{i\in A}p_i\right)\land\left(\bigwedge_{i\notin A}\lnot p_i\right)$$

Each of these formulas is essentially a row in the truth table.

Then taking disjunctions of such formulas $\phi_A$ give you formulas for each equivalence class, since the disjunctions in a way "add" different rows together.

(Note that an empty conjunction is considered vacuously true $\bigwedge_{i\in \emptyset}p_i = \top$, and an empty disjunction is considered vacuously false $\bigvee_{i\in\emptyset}p_i = \bot$)

So, if we have a finite number $m$ of propositional atoms in our premises, we could simply make a list of $2^{2^m}$ formulas that are not equivalent to each other, and see for each of the formulas if it is implied by the premises. The resulting list gives us a set of formulas that are valid when the premises are valid.

By the completeness theorem, there is then a derivation for such formulas, and thus these formulas give us the equivalence classes we were after.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your response. If I may ask, is there a general guide out there that provides step by step examples, and perhaps footnotes detailing in laymen's terms each step?

Comment: @Jim Which parts do you want me to clarify?

Comment: Erm, well, I've never really heard the term "equivalence class" or "Complete", or "atoms", and am not really sure what "length" here means. The length of the statements? Or the number of statements? Don't get me wrong, am certain that these are official terms used in very fancy academic arenas, but I myself am still a student in logic. Am not *new* to logic perse, I can complete proofs and simplify expressions without much difficulty, but it's just that I personally have never come across these terms.

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes and I'll clarify

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I must ask, where did you learn these terms? I think that, whilst I am good at operating within the field of logic itself, my understanding of the metatheory behind it is very much lacking (nonexistent in fact).

Comment: @JimJam I've added some clarification. Learning the terminology goes naturally paired with learning the subject matter: logic. I learned it by doing my degree in mathematics with a specialisation in logic, but if your degree does not offer such courses, reading a good introductory book, such as [Enderton's introduction to mathematical logic](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Enderton+mathematical+logic&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTlanqhu7jAhUUK6YKHTagBcAQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=Enderton%20mathematical%20logic&f=false) is a good place to start.

Comment: Oh, actually am just self-taught haha. Anyway, thank you very much for taking the time to further my understanding. If there's any way I can repay the favour be sure to let me know. I'll be sure to thoroughly read over your content.